# Bigfoot changes hyphenchar for compound words

Tags: hyphenation, bigfoot

Bigfoot changes the “hyphen” char for compound words:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\listfiles
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{foo}
\begin{document}
\footnotefoo{\rule{9.4cm}{1mm} xx compound-word}
\footnote{\rule{9.4cm}{1mm} xx compound-word}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The regular hyphen character (dash) is unchanged. How can I get my dash when using bigfoot/`\footnotefoo` with an explicit dash on compound words? What causes the problem?

```
*File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 bigfoot.sty    2006/07/15 1.25 makes footnotes work
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
manyfoot.sty    2005/09/11 v1.10 Many Footnote Levels Package (NCC)
nccfoots.sty    2005/02/03 v1.2 NCC Footnotes Package (NCC)
  suffix.sty    2006/07/15 1.5 Variant command support
 perpage.sty    2006/07/15 1.12 Reset/sort counters per page
 ***********
```

Comment: You may have an obsolete version of the `bigfoot` package. According to the package's [webpage on the CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/bigfoot/), version 2.0 was release in Oct 2014.

Comment: @Mico The 2.0 doesn't change anything, just tried.

Answer (score 10):

The first is

```
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/8 c
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/8 o
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/8 m
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/8 p
....\kern0.23611
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/8 o
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/8 u
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/8 n
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/8 d
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/8 -
....\discretionary
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
```

But the second is

```
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/8 c
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/8 o
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/8 m
....\discretionary
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/8 -
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/8 p
....\kern0.23611
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/8 o
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/8 u
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/8 n
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/8 d
....\discretionary
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/8 { (ligature --)
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
```

Note the discretionary between m and p, The usual cases this happens are

- `f{}f` breaking ligatures but failing to break them if the word is re-constituted after being considered for hyphenation....

or

- The material being set in an hbox (in which an unfortunate premature optimisation means that discretionaries are not added and then being unboxed).....

Seems like it is the second of these two:

To see the same without `bigfoot`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\rule{9.4cm}{1mm} xxxxx compound-word


\rule{9.4cm}{1mm} xxxxx \setbox0\hbox{compound-word}\unhbox0


\end{document}
```

---

As it's basically a TeX failing it's a bit hard to change bigfoot (or harder than I have time for now) But you can add the discretionary explicitly to make up for TeX not adding it while boxing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bigfoot}
%\showoutput
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{foo}
\begin{document}

\footnotefoo{\rule{9.4cm}{1mm} xx compound\discretionary{-}{}{-}word}
\footnote{\rule{9.4cm}{1mm} xx compound\discretionary{-}{}{-}word}


\end{document}
```

(Or since I'd have put money on you using luatex, you could just fix up the nodelist in lua and replace the -- ligature by -)

Comment: Is there something I can do about that?

Comment: @topskip coming up.... (see edit now and possibly one later:-)

Comment: I'd use `"=` with ngerman/babel, but the text already exists and I (rather: the editor) is not too eager to look through all the pages again. And I wondered if it is my fault or some secret thing TeX is doing. (Using PDFTeX...)

Comment: @topskip some secret thing tex is not doing:-) you can avoid this by never doing `\setbox\z\hbox{....}` and always doing `{\hsize=\maxdimen\setbox0\vbox{....\par\global\setbox1\lastbox}\setbox\z\hbox{\unhbox1\unskip\unskip}`  (If I got that right from memory:-) ie always collect the material in outer hmode not inner, but doing that everywhere someone else's package uses \setbox is a bit much for an answer here

Comment: @topskip "(Using PDFTeX...) " I always knew gambling was a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. (The fine points of TeX...) I will point the author of bigfoot to this.

Comment: @topskip he knows as much about tex boxing internals as anyone:-)

Comment: I know, but this MWE might shorten the bug-searching a bit. The original document is rather complex.

Comment: "basically a TeX failing"?  Does that mean you will be [another] $2.56 richer than before?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I have none of those cheques, and you have to try much harder than this to get a tex bug, basically no behaviour in tex is a bug if any possible, most liberal, reading of the tex book doesn't say categorically that it doesn't happen.

Comment: Better luck next time `;^)`